# Not able to get logs related to azure data factory mapping data flows from log analytics

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics

We are working on implementing a custom logging solution. Most of the information what we need is already present in log analytics from data factory analytics solution but for getting log info on data flows,  there is a challenge. When querying, we get this error in output. "Too large to parse".

Since data flows are complex and critical piece in a pipeline, we are in desperate need to get data like rows copied, skipped, read etc of each activities with in data flow. can you pls help how to get those info?

Comment: This is the output when queried using Kustov query for mapping data flows
{ "errorMessage": "Value is too large to be parsed for logging" }

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same information shown in the ADF portal UI by making a POST request to the below REST endpoint. You can find more information and read about authentication on the following link `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/querybyfactory`

You can choose to query by factory or for a specific pipeline run id depending on your needs.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourcegroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<ADF resource Name>/pipelineruns/<pipeline run id>/queryactivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Below is an example of the data you can get from one stage:

```
{
  "stage": 7,
  "partitionTimes": [
    950
  ],
  "lastUpdateTime": "2020-07-28 18:24:55.604",
  "bytesWritten": 0,
  "bytesRead": 544785954,
  "streams": {
    "CleanData": {
      "type": "select",
      "count": 241231,
      "partitionCounts": [
        950
      ],
      "cached": false
    },
    "ProductData": {
      "type": "source",
      "count": 241231,
      "partitionCounts": [
        950
      ],
      "cached": false
    }
  },
  "target": "MergeWithDeltaLakeTable",
  "time": 67589,
  "progressState": "Completed"
}
```